# Is possible to use Harris corner detector to denoise (delete stars) an image from space?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to know if it is possible to use this function in order to merge all the pixels next to the corner or pixels detected by the Harris corner detector. I was wondering if this is possible to do and how. I have a small piece of code that shows you all the stars and noise detected.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

Home = cv2.imread ("casa.jpg")
Homecopy = casa.copy ()

HomeBW= cv2.cvtColor (Home, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
CasaBW = np.float32 (HomeBW)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris (HomeBW,blockSize=4, ksize=1, k= 0.14)
casa [dst >0.01*dst.max()] = [0,0,255] 


cv2.imshow ("Imagen original", Homecopy)
cv2.imshow ("Esquinas detectadas", Home)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows ()
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t think stars are noise, but of course you can edit them out of the image if you wish. I’m not sure how the Harris corner detector plays into that though.

Comment: I consider the stars as noise when I only want to show the Milky Way core and the surrounding gas.  This is a technique in astrophotography used on photos from nebulas and gas in deep space.